# How do i get postcss and sass to work together for tailwind to work

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, postcss

Right now I am using the default config for angular 8. I want to add tailwind to the project. I created a vanilla angular 8 project and added tailwind with postcss 7 and it works well.

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

I want to know how i can get postcss to play well sass nesting and imports inside components.

Also is there a way to exclude node modules sass imports from compiling with postcss.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd really recommend installing tailwind using this schematic: https://github.com/ngneat/tailwind - it should save you a lot of headaches..

Comment: @MikeOne i ended up upgrading the project and used ngneat worked out pretty well out of the box

Comment: Ah great, glad it worked out for you!